# cannot access postgres running in docker via pg_isready or pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a simple postgres running in docker. Everything works ok. I also can access it via:

`docker exec -it db bash` and there using `psql`.
But both pg_isready and pgAdmin fail to access it via localhost at port 5432

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      frontend:
        aliases:
          - db
```

That's how the container status look like:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                         NAMES
9295d519be2s        postgres             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes             0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp        ebot_db_1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you able to access from host terminal using `psql`?

Comment: no, only if I access this container via bash. It looks like port 5432 is invisible externally but this is not the case. If I check which process occupies 5432 I can see it. That's the response of `lsof -n -i4TCP:5432`: `com.docke 916 chapkovski   18u  IPv6 0xb458da6650204d27      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)`

Comment: Maybe your pg_hba.conf doesn't allow access from anywhere but localhost, please check that. :)